# Confusing use of imperative in a threat

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, imperatives

> 小僧、変なことを**してみろ**。ちょっとでもだ、そしたらクリスマスまでずっと物置に閉じ込めてやる。
> Boy! Do something weird, no matter how small and I'll lock you in your cupboard until Christmas.

Firstly, is してみろ actually imperative here? I don't see what else it could be. Secondly, I'm assuming this is a natural sentence (which past experience with the Harry Potter translation has shown to not always be the case).

This sentence seems somewhat analogous to "try something funny, and I'll *give some punishment*" where, in isolation, "try something funny" looks like it's an imperative, but really it's just omitting an "if you" at the beginning. Obviously the exact same thing isn't happening in the Japanese text, but I wonder if there's some way to think about this sentence<sup>*</sup> that makes it clearer what's going on?

<sub>*I say sentence, but really there are two here. The first 。is not a typo and the fact that the sentence ends here is also a puzzle to me.</sub>

Comment: Actually it should be three sentences with another period after ちょっとでもだ.

Comment: As mentioned in some of the other answers linked above, this sort of thing is actually pretty common in English too.  It's basically just daring somebody to do something.  You could simply translate the above sentences as saying "Boy, (go ahead and) do something weird.  No matter how small it is.  I'll lock you in your cupboard until Christmas."