# Use of Passive form + てみる

Tags: passive-voice, imperatives

> 男が、そんなこと言われてみろ。一、二もなく、なついちまう

How to take the 言われてみろ?

"A guy being told that" + "try being"?

Comment: http://www.ls-japan.org/modules/documents/LSJpapers/journals/145_mori.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It is more or less *try ...ing*, but the translation does not work because the subject is 3rd person.

The usage means *suppose that...*, so *If a guy were told such a thing, then he would ...*

---

In case of 2nd person subject:

- あいつにそんなこと言ってみろ、

*Try saying that to him* should make sense, but it can also be *suppose you say that to him*.

Answer (score 1):

This type of -てみろ is typically used like this:

> 動いてみろ、命はないぞ。
> Move, and you're a dead man.

See:

- [The てごらん structure seems to be a little different in this context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86254/5010)
- [Confusing use of imperative in a threat](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98370/5010)

The original sentence implies "She/You shouldn't say something like that to a man (otherwise something bad will happen)."

You can remember this -てみろ (-てごらん, -てみなさい) as a pattern to dramatically express a *condition* along with its undesirable outcome. When used like this, even though it's in the imperative form, the imperative meaning has been lost, so it can take a third-person subject.